# Powershell Deployed via SCCM Issue

Tags: powershell, output, sccm, network-shares

I am writing a powershell script to be deployed by SCCM via a package. The aim of this is to remove an account with a specific name then write to a file stating if the account exists or not. The code is below:

```
$Computer = hostname
foreach ($C in $Computer) {
    if (Test-Connection $C -Quiet) {
    Write-Verbose "$C > Online"
        $Users = Get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount=True" -ComputerName $C

        if ($Users.Name -contains 'test') {
            Add-Content \\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME.$\$computer-found_$(get-date -Format yyyymmdd_hhmmtt).txt "User 'test' found, Disable 'test' found"
            net user test /active:no            }
        else {
            Add-Content \\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME.$\$computer-notfound_$(get-date -Format yyyymmdd_hhmmtt).txt "User 'test' not found"
        }
    }
    else {
    Write-Verbose "$C > Offline"
    }
}
```

I have also tried replace `Write-Verbose` with `Write-Host` and `Add-Content` with `Out-File` but the problem I having is that no content / file is created when I use the full network path or share e.g. `\\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME.$` the path identified has all the correct permissions and is being ran locally using the System account.

I wanted to see if the issue occured when writing the file locatlly consequently this does not happen when written to `C:\Temp\`

Does anyone have any ideas on to solve this.

Comment: Set-Content? did you try that? are you sure that sharename is correct?

Comment: I presmue it would be something like - Set-content -path C:\test.txt -value "Hello World". I am pretty sure we did.

Comment: Sharename is replacing the sharename that i would use for example \\MYCOMPUTER\LOGS.$\

Comment: how does that work?

Comment: at the very least you should use $c in the share name, not $computer, but what is SHARENAME.$ - is beyond me

Comment: Instead of using the full filepath I have created a share called ....$ I have normalised my code hence the SERVERNAME and SHARENAME variables

Comment: a variable in powershell starts with $ not ends with $

Comment: This is not a powershell variable but a shortened UNC path that can be used as a shortcut to a folder! I have normalised the data!

Comment: The UNC is given to users to access a folder instead of the full file path and the share ends in .$

Comment: why are you referring to $computer instead of $c when constructing path?

Comment: $Computer in the export path is replaced by the hostname! I have tried both and work fine...

Comment: well, in that case what does foreach ($C in $Computer) do? iterates over letters in the word 'hostname'?

Comment: This is currently a one hostname code but has been setup for multiple! Works fine locally just not via sccm when deplpyed

Comment: well, if its multiple values, that must mean its an array, how does that convert to unc, i don't get it? whats you unc path like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127781/discussion-between-terrortot38-and-4c74356b41).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that **local system account** has access to a network resource. I'm not sure if you have ever configured it or not. And what the command you used to run the command

Here I post a working way of doing this using Configuration Manager deployment after testing in my lab.

Basically I created a package with source files 
[image]
and created a task sequence with single "Run Command Line" step. 
[image]
The reason I use a task sequence is because I want to use an account to access the txt file on the network, which I can configure within a task sequence. I don't think Local System Account have such permission.

The script (DeactivateTest.ps1) I use as below just like what you provided and changed a little on the logic:

```
$Computer = hostname
foreach ($C in $Computer) {
    if (Test-Connection $C -Quiet) {
         Write-host "$C > Online"
         $Users = Get-WMIObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount=True" -ComputerName $C
         $result=0
         Foreach($user in $Users){
             if ($User.Name -like '*test*') {
                 $username = $user.Name
                 "`n$(get-date -Format yyyymmdd_hhmmtt) User $username found ON $C, Disable 'test'" | Add-Content \\cas\resource\Result.txt
                 net user $username /active:no 
                 $result+=1
            }}

       if($result =0){
             "`n$(get-date -Format yyyymmdd_hhmmtt) User 'test' not found ON $C" | Add-Content  \\cas\resource\Result.txt}
             }

    else {
    "`n$C is Offline" | Add-Content \\cas\resource\Result.txt
    }
}
```

- The script query local account and disable accounts which have words "Test" in the name. If you don't like this logic, you can change :).
- \\cas\resource\Result.txt is a txt file on the network share. Clients will write result to this txt file.
- The command in the task sequence is (it's a x64 machine):

  PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\DeactiveTest.ps1"

The output is like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I may get downvoted for this as my answer isn't technically directly answering your question, it is, however, intended to try and point you in what may be a more logical direction. All apologies if I offend anyone, but here it is:

Why not just disable the user using Group Policy? If you really want to know where the user is/isn't disabled then you could just use hardware inventory for that, but GP really is the best way to enforce this kind of setting.

Comment: We had the idea of GP's but we want to deploy the software via SCCM. This way we don't need the computers to GPUPDATE! Thanks for your help.